# selected index of particular item in context menu

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
 i have a listbox that shows schedule name,date,time and when i long press the particular item of listbox then it opens a context menu in which i have two items that is add to calendar and view description,so i want that wen i click view description then it will open a popup and display the description of the selected item in a list box.
```

so please tell me how to get the selected index of the context menu???
    my code in xaml is:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="scheduleListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding scheduleList}" Tap="scheduleListbox_Tap" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="150" Width="460">
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add To Calendar"/>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="View Description" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding ScheduleName}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="32"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Text="{Binding ScheduleDate}" Foreground="Red" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="70" Width="460">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Text="{Binding StartTime}" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Text="{Binding EndTime}" Margin="50,5,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

so please tell me how to get the selected index in context menu that wen i click view description on a particular item then it opens a popup and the schedule name and dscription of that particular item is visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click handler for the context menu items, you can use this to get the clicked item:
(replace ScheduleItem with your list item class name)

```
ListBoxItem contextMenuListItem = (ListBoxItem)(scheduleListbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((MenuItem)sender).DataContext));
ScheduleItem item = (ScheduleItem)contextMenuListItem.Content;
```